# How to make the lock-screen keyboard accept the first touch of each key?

Tags: samsung, keyboard

I like to use a password for my lock screen, but my podgy fingers are defeated by the kind efforts of whoever built "intelligence" into the keyboard. However hard I concentrate on being accurate, my finger may touch an adjacent key as I lift it to move to another key. The keyboard interprets this as "ah, you are SLIDING FROM ONE KEY TO ANOTHER. You must be CHANGING YOUR MIND. So instead of taking the key you touched, I will TAKE THE KEY YOU SLID TO."

While I imagine this could theoretically be a feature some people might want, I am not one of them and it only causes grief.

Is there any way to get rid of this feature? Either through settings or by writing an app? I've searched but had zero success.

[samsung-galaxy-ace-4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing a keyboard designed for "big fingers", such as the 1C keyboard. Since you can't change keyboard on the lock screen, you'd have set it as your regular keyboard, meaning it would pop up by default whenever you are entering text. Since you reasonably has the same fingers when typing in general too, this might not be a problem.